# How to get the size of a shared object when using dl_iterate_phdr?

Tags: c, linux, glibc

How to get the size of a shared object when using `dl_iterate_phdr`?

Why is there no size member in `struct dl_phdr_info`?

Do I really need to parse `/proc/self/maps`?

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE

#include <link.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int iterate(struct dl_phdr_info *info, size_t size, void *data)
{
    printf("lib '%s' was loaded at %lx and the size is %i\n", info->dlpi_name, info->dlpi_addr, 0 /* how to get the size? */);
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    dl_iterate_phdr(&iterate, NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The sixth member of the `typedef struct {,,,,,Elf32_Word  p_memsz;   /* Segment size in memory */,...} Elf32_Phdr;` [described on this page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dl_iterate_phdr.3.html) may be what you are looking for?

Comment: @ryyker No, that's the size of a single section (for example `.text`).

Comment: This seems relevant: [**How do you detect the size of a dynamic library(shared object) in the current process?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71182137/how-do-you-detect-the-size-of-a-dynamic-libraryshared-object-in-the-current-pr)  I'll let others decide if this question is a dupe of that.